# Will Vibrator.vibrate throw an error if the device can't vibrate?

Tags: android-vibration

I'm hoping not, but just wanted to get a definitive answer since its not stated in the docs. Do I have to check with Vibrate.hasVibrator before vibrating?

Comment: Just run an emulator with a device without vibrate?

Comment: Why *not* check first? That way, if you can't vibrate, you'll know it and can (if it's sensible to do so) use some other method of notifying the device user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the source code of [`android.os.Vibrator`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/os/Vibrator.java), `vibrate()` will not throw anything:

```
public void vibrate(long milliseconds)
{
    try {
        mService.vibrate(milliseconds, mToken);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: And neither will cancel()! Thanks!